# Using dot notation with variable to get object value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a config object like this

```
{ config: {
    params: {
        football: {
            url: ''
        },
        soccer: {
            url: ''
        }
    }
}
```

I simply need to get at the `football` or `soccer` url value using a variable, so something like

```
let sport = 'soccer';

let path = config.params.`sport`.url;
```

I've tried bracket notation like `config.params[sport]` and the `eval` function but neither seem to do the trick.  I'm sure I'm misnaming what I'm trying to do which is likely why I can't seem to find an answer.

thanks

Comment: What is the output of config.params['soccer'] ?

Comment: `config.params[sport]` — You forgot the *variable* name at the front. You need to access the object before you can access the `config` property within it.

Comment: Its either football or soccer, sport isn't defined.  If you want to use 'sport' variable as a look up then its config.params[sport].url

Comment: @SPlatten — `let sport = 'soccer';`

Comment: @Quentin, Yes, ty, see my edit.

Comment: @SPlatten — Quote: "I've tried bracket notation like config.params[sport]"

Comment: "I've tried bracket notation like `config.params[sport]`" it should be `rootObjVariableName.config.params[sport].url`. where `const rootObjVariableName = { config: {...}}`

Comment: Or to keep reference schema consistent, use:  variable['config']['params'][sport]['url']

Comment: @SPlatten — That's slow to type and hard to read. It's consistant to use dot notation for static references and square bracket notation when you need to use a variable (i.e. using syntax to highlight when you are using a variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea.

```js
const sport = 'soccer'
const data = {
  config: {
    params: {
      football: {
        url: '1'
      },
      soccer: {
        url: '2'
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(data.config.params[sport].url)
```

Comment: thx i'm not sure what happened - I swear I tried it like this but was getting undefined - maybe different compilation error but it works now (wish I could delete this) :)